# How to set Anti-Aliasing Method in Unity Post-Processing Stack through script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, antialiasing

I have a dropdown menu that contains the following selections.

- OFF
- FXAA
- TAA

I am trying to manipulate the anti-aliasing method of Unity's PostProcessing Stack asset through dropdown menu. The OFF does work since it just disables the anti aliasing but the rest does not work. What is the proper way upon changing the method of AA on this asset?

Here's my current code:

```
void AntiAliasLevel(int index)
{
    var uiAA = ui.antialiasing.settings.method;
    var InGameAA = InGame.antialiasing.settings.method;
    var taa = AntialiasingModel.Method.Taa;

    switch (index)
    {
        case 0:
            InGame.antialiasing.enabled = false;
            ui.antialiasing.enabled = false;
            break;
        case 1:
            InGame.antialiasing.enabled = true;
            ui.antialiasing.enabled = true;

            uiAA = taa;
            break;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the settings to a variable, make the change, and then assign the variable back to the settings.

```
var settings = InGame.antialiasing.settings;
settings.method = AntialiasingModel.Method.Taa;
InGame.antialiasing.settings = settings;
```